# How to read from an ID list in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of IDs (`Future<List<String>> _listaIdEmpresasF`) and I would like to query data based on each ID in the list. I'm using two FutureBuilders: The first one to get the list of IDs, and the second one to display the data related of each ID.

My code looks like this...

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listaIdEmpresasF = _usuarioBloc.cargarEmpresasDeUsuario(_prefs.idUsuario);
  }
```

---

```
  Widget _crearListado(BuildContext context) {


  return FutureBuilder(
    future: _listaIdEmpresasF, 
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.connectionState);
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData != null){ 
          final List<String> _listaIdEmpresas = snapshot.data;

          return FutureBuilder(
            future: _empresaDatosBloc.cargarEmpresaDatosListado(_listaIdEmpresas),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot2) {
              print(snapshot2.connectionState);
              if (snapshot2.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot2.hasdata) {
                final List<EmpresaDatosModel> _listaEmpresas = snapshot2.data;
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _listaEmpresas.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return _crearItem(context, _listaEmpresas[i], i);
                      },

                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ); 
              } else return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('Preloader.gif'), height: 500.0,)),
              );
            },
          );
        } 
        else return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('Preloader.gif'), height: 500.0,)),
        );
    },
  );
}
```

To get the data from each ID, I'm using a loop as follows:

```
Future<List<EmpresaDatosModel>> cargarEmpresaDatosListado(List<String> listaIdEmpresas) async {

    final List<EmpresaDatosModel> listaEmpresas = new List(); 

    listaIdEmpresas.forEach((id) async {
      Query resp = db.child('empresas/$id/datos');

      final snapshot = await resp.once();

      if (snapshot.value == null) return [];

      final temp = EmpresaDatosModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(snapshot.value));
      temp.idEmpresa = id;
      listaEmpresas.add(temp);
      print('${temp.nombre} subida');

      await resp.once().then((snapshot) {
        print("Los Datos de una Empresa se cargaron totalmente - ${temp.nombre}");
      });
    });
    listaEmpresas.forEach((element) {print('Emp ${element.nombre}');});
    return listaEmpresas; 
}
```

**The problem:** I can't be able to obtain the full data. For example, if I have three IDs in _listaIdEmpresas, sometimes the app displays a list of one company (related to the first ID), sometimes two companies (first and secod ID) and sometimes the three companies. I supposed this is because the ConnectionState of the second snapshot is done before reading all three loops..

I tried to add a condition but it didn't work...

```
      if (snapshot2.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot2.data.length == _listaIdEmpresas.length)
```

I cannot query all companies and filter it as a list of companies due to query security rules that I configured.

I would like to include the specific list of IDs in the query parameters, but I don't know if it's possible.

How is the right way to read data from a list of IDs?

Answer (score 0):

snapshot.key will give you the id of the item

Comment: Are you suggesting an orderbykey query? How to query in an specific List of IDs as a parameter?